# Power builder OLEObject type equivalent in C# (.Net 4.0)

Tags: c#, builder

I am migrating Power builder application into .Net 4.0(c#).
I need help regarding OLEObject type used in Power builder code. Below are the code example.

OLEObject test;

test = MyClass.GetContext();

int value = test.get("on")

Please tell me what the equivalent of OLEObject of Power Builder in C#??
Please response ASAP. Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

The C# version 4 *dynamic* keyword.

If you're stuck on an earlier version then you're better off writing the code in VB.NET.  Doing late binding in C# is pretty ugly.